# Why my cell in my collection view getting deselected when i start scrolling horizontally?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift5

I want to make a simple calendar from a collection view. [enter image description here][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yXhL.jpg
But when i select a cell and starts scrolling the cell get deselected automatically. Here is my code for the collection view.

```
    `let todayColor = UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 56/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1)
    let otherDayColor = UIColor(red: 90/255, green: 90/255, blue: 90/255, alpha: 1)
var now = Date()
    var day = DateFormatter()
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath) as! CalenderCell
                        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                        cell.backgroundColor = otherDayColor
                        if indexPath.row == 0{
                            cell.backgroundColor = todayColor
                            cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date()) - 1])
                            cell.dateLabel.text = now.string(format: "dd")
                        }
                        else if indexPath.row == 1{
                            cell.backgroundColor = otherDayColor
                            cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 1)) - 1])
                            cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 1).string(format: "dd")
                        }
                        else if indexPath.row == 2{
                            cell.backgroundColor = otherDayColor
                            cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 2)) - 1])
                            cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 2).string(format: "dd")
                        }
                        else if indexPath.row == 3{
                            cell.backgroundColor = otherDayColor
                            cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 3)) - 1])
                            cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 3).string(format: "dd")
                        }
                        else if indexPath.row == 4{
                            cell.backgroundColor = otherDayColor
                            cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 4)) - 1])
                            cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 4).string(format: "dd")
                        }
                        else if indexPath.row == 5{
                            cell.backgroundColor = otherDayColor
                            cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 5)) - 1])
                            cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 5).string(format: "dd")
            }
            else if indexPath.row == 6{
            cell.backgroundColor = otherDayColor
            cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 6)) - 1])
            cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 6).string(format: "dd")
            }
            return cell
            }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath){
                    if indexPath.row == 0{
                        cell.backgroundColor = todayColor
                    }
                    else{
                        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
                    }
                }
            }

            func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath){
                    cell.backgroundColor = otherDayColor
                }
            }`
```

Comment: cell deselected once it goes out screen and then comes in ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you configure selection color in the `didSelect` method, but in the `cellForItemAt` - not. You need to create variable with selected item index (and set it at `didSelect`) and update color management in the `cellForItemAt`.

Implement selected item index in your view controller:

```
var selectedItem: Int?
```

in your collection view delegate methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath) as! CalenderCell
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cell.backgroundColor = otherDayColor
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date()) - 1])
        cell.dateLabel.text = now.string(format: "dd")
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1{
        cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 1)) - 1])
        cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 1).string(format: "dd")
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2{
        cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 2)) - 1])
        cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 2).string(format: "dd")
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 3{
        cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 3)) - 1])
        cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 3).string(format: "dd")
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 4{
        cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 4)) - 1])
        cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 4).string(format: "dd")
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 5{
        cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 5)) - 1])
        cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 5).string(format: "dd")
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 6{
        cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 6)) - 1])
        cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 6).string(format: "dd")
    }

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = todayColor
    } else {
        if let selectedItem = selectedItem,
           selectedItem == indexPath.row {
            // this cell is selected
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = otherDayColor
        }
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        selectedItem = indexPath.row // set selectedItem
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.backgroundColor = todayColor
        } else{
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
        }
    }
}
```

In the `didDeselectItemAt` need to set selectedItem to nil.

Also is good to use `switch-case` instead many of `if`

Comment: No. the problem is same. Only the last cell gets deselected when i scroll all other cell are working perfectly.

Comment: Have you set selectedItem = indexPath.row in the 'didSelectItemAt' ?

Comment: Yes, i have added it in my didSelectItemAtIndex function.

Comment: add for debug in the 'cellForItemAt' at bottom:
cell.dateLabel.textColor = cell.backgroundColor